# How to deny https requests to my servers public ip address

Tags: apache, ssl, virtual-hosts

I have a server running Apache 2 that has 6 virtual hosts. All the virtual hosts run over SSL. However if you make a request to my server's IP (for example: https://11.22.33.444) since there is no certificate for my IP you are redirected to the last virtual host alphabetically and whatever app is linked to that virtual host will load over https://11.22.33.444.

My question is how can I either

1. redirect any traffic loading over my server's public IP address to an error page
   OR
2. Deny any traffic loading over my server's public IP address and shutdown the connection

Answer (score 1):

Apache prioritizes VirtualHosts in terms of order. By putting a very basic server at the top, it will redirect all traffic (that doesn't satisfy the other virtual hosts) to that webpage.

```
#default server b/c first

<VirtualHost *:80>
        Redirect 302 / https://www.mainsite.com/error_page
</VirtualHost>

#main server

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mainsite.com
        DocumentRoot ...
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile.....etc.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.secondsite.com
        DocumentRoot ...
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile.....etc.
</VirtualHost>

#force https servers

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mainsite.com
        Redirect 301 / https://www.mainsite.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName portfolio.secondsite.com
        Redirect 301 / https://www.secondsite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This technique is known as the default/catch-all vhost ( https://serverfault.com/questions/82306/apache-default-catch-all-virtual-host).

Comment: @arjunpat Thank you for your quick response. My issue with your answer is that it doesn't redirect https traffic loading over my server's IP it only redirects http traffic loading over my server's IP

Comment: @Tyler 1 month later — for me, redirecting https traffic didn't really matter because, by default, all browsers go to http (port 80). If someone deliberately put in https, they would just get a warning saying they had a bad certificate which I don't think is all that bad.

Comment: @arjunpat Thank you for the reply. My issue with your implementation is that I would like it to be a bit more robust. If they deliberately type in https and get to the warning but also click "proceed" they will get routed to the last virtual host alphabetically. I would ultimately like them get routed to a generic error page via some sort of default virtual host that accepts https requests.